# python patch not patching out tested class

Tags: python-3.x, python-unittest, python-mock

I'm trying to set up some unit tests for `gateway.py`. When I call the below test code once im inside gateway.py(debugging) it doesn't seem to mock out the os.environ call

```
os.environ
environ({'PATH': '.....'})

os.environ['x']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/justin/.IdeaIC2019.3/config/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_exec2.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec(exp, global_vars, local_vars)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'x'
```

test file:

```
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import mock

from httmock import urlmatch, HTTMock
import requests


class TestGateway(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch('gateway.os.environ',  mock.MagicMock(return_value="mock_env_var"))
    def test_zoho_event(self, mock_os):
        mock_os.environ.assert_called()
```

my directory structure:

```
.
├── docker
│   ├── flask
│   │   ├── Dockerfile
│   │   └── prod_vars.env
│   └── nginx
│       ├── x.gateway.com.au.conf
│       ├── Dockerfile
│       └── nginx.conf
├── docker-compose.yml
├── gateway.ini
├── gateway.py
├── Jenkinsfile
├── logs
│   └── gateway.log
├── __pycache__
│   ├── gateway.cpython-36.pyc
│   ├── test_gateway.cpython-36.pyc
│   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc
├── requirements.txt
├── test_gateway.py
└── wsgi.py
```

I have reread https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch many times and I am sure I am patching where the function is loaded from which is inside gateway.py. Not sure what im missing?

Comment: Patching `'gateway.os.environ'` looks wrong. Either you `import os` in gateway - in this case you have to patch `'os.environ'`, or you do `from os import environ` - in this case you should patch `'gateway.environ'` (you probably found out meanwhile).

Comment: thanks for your reply @MrBeanBremen, you are correct. I was not patching the correct namespace as mentioned in more detail here https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch